# Does restFB API support content_publishing_limit from Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram-graph-api, restfb

Checking [last releases](https://github.com/restfb/restfb/releases/tag/v2022.9.0) seems to be that the endpoint [content_publishing_limit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/content_publishing_limit) is something not supported yet. Does anyone knows if this will be supported soon? Or how can I raise a request for it? The team is currently working on whatsapp integration, so not sure if the endpoint is somewhere there or was missed, and the repo send me here to ask my questions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open an Issue on the [RestFB Github repository](https://github.com/restfb/restfb). Please add the links and JSON (if you have some). Then we try to add the objects to the next release. So you can use the endpoint. Or you can code the objects and provide a PR.

Comment: Thanks for include it so quickly! One more question, do you have an expected release date for this changes? I'll need that in the nearly feature and I'm only asking to know what would be my next step, not to put pressure or something like that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the next few days :D

Comment: Thank you! Can't wait for it :^D

Comment: RestFB 2022.10.0 is released